# requests get image, return via flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to get an image via requests and return that image from a flask application. I've not having any luck reading the binary data from the request, my resulting response is always 0 bytes.

```
@app.route('/image')
def get_image:
    zs = requests.Session()
    r = zs.get( 'url_that_loads_a_png' )
    fr = make_response( r.raw.read() )
    fr.headers['Content-Type'] = r.headers['Content-Type']
    return fr
```

I assume my `make_response( r.raw.read() )` is somehow incorrect, but I'm not sure what it should be. I've searched for other answers and based the above on them, but they are always slightly different (usually involving a file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not making a streaming request, so the raw socket has *already* been read from. Just use `r.content` instead:

```
fr = make_response(r.content)
```

The raw socket can only be read from still if you used `stream=True` when creating the request:

```
r = zs.get('url_that_loads_a_png', stream=True)
```

but since you are reading the whole response into memory *anyway* there is not much point in doing so here.